# StackOverFlow while change editText

Tags: android, stack-overflow

I have three EditText. I want to listen to the changes in each of the input and change them automatically given input value. But when there is a change, listeners recursively starting to change each other and I catch java.lang.StackOverFlow. What do I do?

I make changes in ediText's in **afterTextChanged(Editable s)**.

```
priceEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    try {
                        if (priceForLiterEditText.getText().length() > 0 && isPriceFocused) {
                            double summ = Double.valueOf(priceEditText.getText().toString());
                            double literPrice = Double.valueOf(priceForLiterEditText.getText().toString());
                            summ = summ / literPrice;
                            summ = Math.round(summ * 100);
                            summ /= 100;
                            fuelLitersAmountEditText.setText(String.valueOf(summ));
                            fuelLitersAmountTextView.setText(String.valueOf(summ) + " " + currentCar.getCurrencyName(getApplicationContext()));
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                }
            });
```

> ATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.StackOverflowError
>               at android.graphics.Paint.set(Paint.java:481)
>               at android.text.TextPaint.set(TextPaint.java:61)
>               at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:1091)
>               at android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:599)
>               at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:462)
>               at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:852)
>               at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:829)
>               at android.text.Layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(Layout.java:813)
>               at android.widget.TextView.getFocusedRect(TextView.java:5602)
>               at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocusInAbsoluteDirection(FocusFinder.java:231)
>               at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:163)
>               at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:94)
>               at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:65)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:680)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:682)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:682)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:682)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:682)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:682)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:682)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:682)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:682)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:682)
>               at android.view.View.focusSearch(View.java:6456)
>               at android.widget.TextView.onCreateInputConnection(TextView.java:6245)
>               at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner(InputMethodManager.java:1168)
>               at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.restartInput(InputMethodManager.java:1119)
>               at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4019)
>               at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3927)
>               at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:104)
>               at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3902)
>               at com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClientTest.RefillActivity$9$2.afterTextChanged(RefillActivity.java:866)
>               at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7986)
>               at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4114)
>               at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3927)
>               at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:104)
>               at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3902)
>               at com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClientTest.RefillActivity$11$2.afterTextChanged(RefillActivity.java:1012)
>               at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7986)
>               at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4114)
>               at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3927)
>               at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:104)
>               at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3902)
>               at com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClientTest.RefillActivity$9$2.afterTextChanged(RefillActivity.java:866)
>               at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7986)
>               at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4114)
>               at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3927)
>               at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:104)
>               at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3902)
>               at com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClientTest.RefillActivity$11$2.afterTextChanged(RefillActivity.java:1012)
>               at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7986)
>               at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4114)
>               at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3927)
>               at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:104)
>               at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3902)
>               at com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClientTest.RefillActivity$9$2.afterTextChanged(RefillActivity.java:866)
>               at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7986)
>               at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4114)
>               at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3927)
>               at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:104)
>               at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3902)
>               at com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClientTest.RefillActivity$11$2.afterTextChanged(RefillActivity.java:1012)

Comment: Post your logcat error

Comment: Is this listener only attached to one edittext field?

Comment: Added logs. No, I listen all 3 fields

Comment: Maybe the string is too long to print. Try rounding off to 2-3 places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the TextChangedListeners triggering each other. You should add a check to only do it on whichever field the user input is directed to.

```
com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClientTest.RefillActivity$11$2.afterTextChanged(RefillActivity.java:1012)
com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClientTest.RefillActivity$9$2.afterTextChanged(RefillActivity.java:866)
com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClientTest.RefillActivity$11$2.afterTextChanged(RefillActivity.java:1012)
com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClientTest.RefillActivity$9$2.afterTextChanged(RefillActivity.java:866)
...
```